# Spring Security - Multiple Sessions depending on usage (login/httpBasic)

Tags: java, spring, rest, session, spring-security

I have a project where I have one application "a" with rest services and another one ("b") for a web page where the users can login and use 1 or 2 rest services of "a" (e.g. posting a comment).
The problem is, the rest services are all secured and shall authorize via httpBasic every time (no session).
The services needed for "b" on the other hand shall have a session.
so:
requests with the rest services directly -> httpBasic everytime(no session)
login via webpage/webpage handling requests -> session via login

Is there a way to achieve this? My only solution right now would be to delete the session after the httpBasic process, but I don't know how to do that.

```
    httpSecurity.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
    .and().httpBasic();
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is there a way to do what? You want the webpage to login with every access to the rest service?

Comment: Im sorry, its more like this:
I wanna call my webservices directly over a client, those shall always authorize via httpBasic header - no session shall be created this way.
But I also got a webpage, where it is necessary to login (to get a session) before posting messages, comments, etc (webservices). Those shall be authorized via the session.

Comment: same thing isn't it? The webpage needs to store the authorization header in the session and send it every time.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you really wish to delete session data it can be achieved by implementing LogoutSuccessHandler interface.

```
        package com.arjun.security;

        import java.io.IOException;

        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
        import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

        import com.informage.arnav.domain.CassandraLoginSession;

        @Service
        public class AppLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

            @Autowired
            private CassandraLoginSessionDao cassandraLoginSessionDao;

            public AppLogoutSuccessHandler() {
                super();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

                if (authentication != null) {
                    final Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
                    final AppUserDetails appUserDetails;
                    if (principal != null && principal instanceof AppUserDetails) {
                        appUserDetails = (AppUserDetails) principal;
                CassandraLoginSession cassandraLoginSession=cassandraLoginSessionDao.findBySessionId(appUserDetails.getSessionId().toString());
            //can also delete based on userId                
            //CassandraLoginSession cassandraLoginSession=cassandraLoginSessionDao.findByUserId(appUserDetails.getUserId());
                        cassandraLoginSessionDao.hardDelete(cassandraLoginSession);
            //delete the session data from DB where session is stored
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

In your security configuration you need to configure this handler.

```
<logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="appLogoutSuccessHandler" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write following to permit access to your webservice without login:

```
http.authorizeRequests()    
    .antMatchers("/webserviceNotRequiredAuthorization*").permitAll();
```

Then you must write following to which you webservices need authorization :

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/webserviceRequiredAuthorization").hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
```

in short first write the URL pattern for which authorization is not required and then write the URL pattern for which authorization is required.

```
http.authorizeRequests()    
    .antMatchers("/webserviceNotRequiredAuthorization*").permitAll();    

http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/webserviceRequiredAuthorization").hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
```